# Execute python script From web browser(http/curl Request)

Tags: python, http, curl, nginx

I'm quit new with python, I use basic python for scripting, but never used for HTTP request.
I used to learn django, wsgi but all tutorials have website development guidance

1- I don't want to build any website, just want to make python executable 
   from remote example:(http://www.example.com/test.py) like PHP.

2- There is one python file called test.py, has some functions like 
   retrieving info from database.
   Deploying some services on cloud and returning status.

3- Nginx for web server & REST API Methods.

I really appreciate if someone can help me :)

Comment: This will help http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Comment: Thank you so much...
This is what i was looking for.... It helped me lot. You saved my time as i already wasted more time.